Twin-T Notch has output with no input
For Context: I am trying to implement a hardware Twin-T Notch Filter to attenuate 50Hz PLI in a sEMG circuit. I've used the circuit proposed by Analog Devices on page 17 of the AD8244 datasheet, but with slightly varied values as shown below. It works, and the adjustable QF lets me adjust the bandwidth affected at a cost of attenuation depth, as expected. However, it doesn't attenuate enough and I want to cascade it at a tight bandwidth (40-60Hz) to try attenuate more without sacrificing the surrounding frequencies as much.

The Problem: Whenever I power the IC for the circuit and view the output with my oscilloscope while applying no input to the circuit, there is a 50Hz signal. It increases in amplitude as R11 decreases. For example at 167Ohms it has a Vp-p of 270mV and at 1.3kOhms is has a Vp-p of 40mV. I want to set R11 at or below 1k for the cascade, to keep a narrower bandwidth. When I use a signal generator to apply a sine wave, and vary the frequency, it attenuates as expected but this disturbance is still present.
Is this just a feature of the circuit or is there a way to keep a high QF without this disturbance?

If your input has no path to ground, picking up power supply noise is normal.

I am a very silly person. I assumed the Notch was causing it as it was a 50Hz signal coming from a notch attenuating 50Hz. Really it is just PLI that affects the end of the circuit and doesn't get attenuated. Hence why with no input, it still occurs. I tested by changing the center frequency of the notch and the disturbance stayed at 50Hz.


.....while applying no input to the circuit, there is a 50Hz signal

A voltage source needs to be applied at the input port even if that voltage source is 0 volts. Leaving the input port open-circuit invalidates the effect of the notch filter and all bets are off regarding performance. Even a 1 kohm to ground would be OK but, don't open circuit it because that is fundamentally changing the circuit.
Apart from that, leaving the input port open circuit does not provide a sensible bias point for pin 10 on U2D i.e. it will float and produce nonsensical signals at its output.

I've applied ground to the input before but only directly, tomorrow I will try applying it over a resistor like you've said. Even when I supply it a signal from a function generator through the rest of my circuit, it has had the same disturbance.

@LukeDettorre if it doesn't work with the equivalent impedance of a signal generator (presumably 50 ohm) then it won't work with 1 kohm. You might need to dial-back the notchiness of your circuit until it reaches stability or, add a buffer driver stage before the input.

You should adjust your components values ...
Here is the non-adjusted components

And here some adjusted for the 50 Hz frequency ... Could do better.

Note also that 50 Hz noise could be "random" with "0.1% position" frequency...
